# Check the type of a tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Suppose I have a table that contains a list of tr and th, I need to know if the current tag in iteration is a th or a tr, what I did for the moment:

```
foreach (var tr in rows)
{   
    if(tr.InnerHtml.StartsWith("<th"))
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Name` property](http://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v410/html/2e92e931-28d5-c727-2de9-32e12c8f17d3.htm):

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in rows)
{   
    if(node.Name == "tr")
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```